# How do you add template text to a textview that wont be published

Tags: android

How do you add some template text to a text view, that will only be visible on the designer in Android Studio and maybe in debug, but not when publishing the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding `tools`attribute, text will be visible only to the `design` area and not runtime.

```
 <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  <!--add this-->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="examle text"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLightGray"/>

 </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: And you can do a lot more with the `tools` namespace: http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes